# How to call parent class method from it's constructor

Tags: java

I am creating child class object. I know parent class constructor called first .If i want to call parent class print method so I am used `this.print()` but this is not working.
Please suggest me how to call parent class `print()` method without creating parent class object.

```
public class Test
        {
            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
                Child Child = new Child();
            }
        }
    
        class Parent
        {   
            void print()
            {
                System.out.println("parent class print method");
            }
    
            Parent()
            {
                this.print();
            }
        }    
    
        class Child extends Parent
        {
            void print()
            {
                System.out.println("child class print method ");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

in child `constructor` You can  call a super class method like :

```
super.print();
```

see  [**java docs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

```
public class Superclass {

    public void printMethod() {
        System.out.println("Printed in Superclass.");
    }
}    



public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    // overrides printMethod in Superclass
    public void printMethod() {
        super.printMethod();
        System.out.println("Printed in Subclass");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subclass s = new Subclass();
        s.printMethod();    
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I can call the parent class method from child class by using super keyword but I want to call parent method from parent class constructor.How can this happens?

Comment: Its one and same that calling a method inside the constructor ..right ??

Comment: "I want to call parent method from parent class constructor"  what does this mean ??

Comment: If i am ruuning above prgram then i got following output >>child class print method  but i want this output>>parent class print method

Comment: i just want to know why child class print() method calls though i am using this.print()?

Answer (score 1):

To call any parent method use `super`. This also works for the constructor:

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    void print()
    {
        System.out.println("child class print method ");
    }

    Child() {
        super.print(); // parent print method

        this.print(); // child print method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"this" keyword refers to current class and "super" keyword refers to its parent class or interface which it extends or implements respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Clear my concept thanks to anwser my question..

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Child Child = new Child();
    }
}

class Parent
{   
    void print()
    {
        System.out.println("parent class print method");
    }

    Parent()
    {
        this.print();
    }
}    

class Child extends Parent
{
    void print()
    {
        super.print();
    }
}
```

output:

```
parent class print method
```